# How to change the login (gdm) font and font-size?

Tags: 11.04, fonts, login, gdm

In Ubuntu 09.04 to 10.10, I was able to do this using the following method:

```
sudo cp /usr/share/applications/gnome-appearance-properties.desktop /usr/share/gdm/autostart/LoginWindow
```

to enable Appearance Preferences at login.

And:

```
sudo unlink /usr/share/gdm/autostart/LoginWindow/gnome-appearance-properties.desktop
```

To disable the above feature.

This no longer works in 11.04.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Curious question - if you do the following and logout:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/share/applications/gnome-appearance-properties.desktop /usr/share/gdm/autostart/LoginWindow/gnome-appearance-properties.desktop
```

You will see:

[image]

As you can see I've italicised the login font.

To prevent the appearance window from appearing, login and then run:

```
sudo rm /usr/share/gdm/autostart/LoginWindow/gnome-appearance-properties.desktop
```

Comment: Works perfectly, similar as previous versions of Ubuntu.